# Solr: Multiple Schema with Multiple Cores

Tags: solr, sharding

Currently I had 2 different schema set (setA/ and setB/) sitting under multicore/ folder in a jetty solr path /opt/solr/example/multicore.

If I wanna create shads for each schema, how should I go about it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two shards will have the same configuration, but different documents. So you make a copy of your configuration on a new server, then put half the documents on each server.

The [Solr page on distributed search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) gives a little bit of information about querying across multiple shards.